# Can someone help me plot the spectrum as shown in the figure in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have to plot the freuency spectrum of a similar pulse echo response in m project, can someone help me here?

[image]

Comment: Well, have you tried using the FFT command?

Comment: Hi yes i did try the fft command but it didnt work. i got 2 narrow peaks at either ends of the spectrum

Comment: Well, you have to zoom your spectrum to the range of interest. The plot you are showing is zoomed for sure, it shows only a small excerpt (20 to 50 MHz).